# IntelliJ does not show table relations

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, diagram

```
create table OP_ORDER (
  ORDER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  CREATION_DATE DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  APPROVAL_DATE DATETIME,
  ORDERED_CAR_ID BIGINT,
  DUE_DATE DATETIME not null,
  PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID VARCHAR(64),
  ORDER_STATUS varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  DECLINE_MESSAGE VARCHAR(2048),
  ORDER_TYPE varchar(128),
  APPROVER_ID BIGINT
);    

create table OP_ORDERED_CAR (
  ORDERED_CAR_ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  CAR_TYPE VARCHAR(128),
  OFFER_NUMBER VARCHAR(128),
  MAKE VARCHAR(128),
  MODELL VARCHAR(128)
);

alter table OP_ORDER
    add constraint OP_ORDER_OP_ORDERED_CAR_ID_fk
        foreign key (ORDERED_CAR_ID) references OP_ORDERED_CAR(ORDERED_CAR_ID)
            on delete cascade
;
```

So clearly the two tables have a relationship. But when in IntelliJ I create a diagram of these two tables, it does now show me that relation (like kind of an arrow going from one table to the other):

[image]

Comment: Which is why it's called a STRUCTURED QUERY language. It's the QUERY that provides the STRUCTURE

Comment: Whats the matter with showing an arrow from op_order to op_ordered_car that shows the referenced columns?

Answer (score 1):

There seems [to be a bug](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206445409-Diagram-not-showing-relation-Foreign-Key-constraint-is-there-) (quite old) that has not yet been addressed.

It happened to me too, it was working and out of a sudden, it wasn't anymore.